# Unable to access the aws health endpoint

Tags: amazon-web-services

AWS Health has a single global endpoint: https://health.us-east-1.amazonaws.com
when open the endpoint I am getting an error. any idea?

```
issing AuthenticationTokenException>
  <Message>Missing Authentication Token</Message>
</MissingAuthenticationTokenException>
```

How can I get open issues via API from the personal dashboard ?https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-aws-personal-health-dashboard-status-you-can-relate-to/

Comment: It looks as if you need to include your authentication token within your request.

Comment: Try logging into the AWS Management Console first.

Comment: I have tried both somehow it didn't work for me